# Xamarin Android file path to long

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

When I try to build my Xamarin project I always get the following error.

> The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

Of course I Googled this error and found out that it is quite common, so I tried a lot of different solutions. I moved all my project files and my Android SDK, NDK's etc directly to C:. I also set my TEMP folder at C:\TEMP. However, non of this seems to help. When I look at the line of code that gives this error, Visual Studio sends me to this line of code in Xamarin.Android.Common.targets.

```
<Target Name="_BuildAdditionalResourcesCache"
  Inputs="@(ReferencePath);@(ReferenceDependencyPaths)"
  Outputs="$(_AndroidResourcePathsCache)"
 >
 <GetAdditionalResourcesFromAssemblies
  AndroidSdkDirectory="$(_AndroidSdkDirectory)"
  AndroidNdkDirectory="$(_AndroidNdkDirectory)"
  Assemblies="@(ReferencePath);@(ReferenceDependencyPaths)"
  CacheFile="$(_AndroidResourcePathsCache)"
  Condition=" '$(DesignTimeBuild)' != 'true' "
 />
</Target>
```

The error points to the fourth line to be specific. I can't modify this file so I didn't try anything here.

I really don't know what to try anymore, so any solutions are very welcome! I already tried to uninstall and re-install Visual Studio and Xamarin, this didn't work either. The project runs fine on other computers.

EDIT:
My Stack Trace

```
2>Target "_ValidateResourceCache" in file "C:\Program Files 
(x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets" from project "C:\MyProject\Droid\MyProject.Droid.csproj" (target "_GetAdditionalResourcesFromAssemblies" depends on it):
2>Task "ReadAdditionalResourcesFromAssemblyCache" skipped, due to false condition; (Exists('$(_AndroidResourcePathsCache)')) was evaluated as (Exists('obj\Release\resourcepaths.cache')).
2>Task "Delete" skipped, due to false condition; ( '$(_IsResourceCacheValid)' == 'False' ) was evaluated as ( '' == 'False' ).
2>Done building target "_ValidateResourceCache" in project "MyProject.Droid.csproj".
2>Target "_SetupDesignTimeBuildForIntellisense" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets" from project "C:\MyProject\Droid\MyProject.Droid.csproj" (target "_BuildAdditionalResourcesCache" depends on it):
2>Done building target "_SetupDesignTimeBuildForIntellisense" in project "MyProject.Droid.csproj".
2>Target "_BuildAdditionalResourcesCache" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets" from project "C:\MyProject\Droid\MyProject.Droid.csproj" (target "_GetAdditionalResourcesFromAssemblies" depends on it):
2>Building target "_BuildAdditionalResourcesCache" completely.
2>Output file "obj\Release\resourcepaths.cache" does not exist.
2>Using "GetAdditionalResourcesFromAssemblies" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Build.Tasks.dll".
2>Task "GetAdditionalResourcesFromAssemblies"
2>  GetAdditionalResourcesFromAssemblies Task
2>    AndroidSdkDirectory: C:\Android\android-sdk\
2>    AndroidNdkDirectory: C:\Android\android-ndk-r10e\
2>    Assemblies: 
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Java.Interop.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\bin\Release\MyProject.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Async.1.0.168\lib\portable-net45+win8+wpa81\Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Async.1.0.168\lib\portable-net45+win8+wpa81\Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v6.0\Mono.Android.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v6.0\Mono.Android.Export.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\mscorlib.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.8.0.3\lib\portable-net45+wp80+win8+wpa81+dnxcore50\Newtonsoft.Json.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\refit.2.4.1\lib\MonoAndroid\Refit.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\SQLite.Net.Core-PCL.3.1.1\lib\portable-win8+net45+wp8+wpa81+MonoAndroid1+MonoTouch1\SQLite.Net.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\SQLite.Net-PCL.3.1.1\lib\MonoAndroid\SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\Square.OkHttp.2.7.5.0\lib\MonoAndroid\Square.OkHttp.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\Square.OkIO.1.6.0.0\lib\MonoAndroid\Square.OkIO.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Core.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Net.Http.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\Microsoft.Net.Http.2.2.29\lib\monoandroid\System.Net.Http.Extensions.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\Microsoft.Net.Http.2.2.29\lib\monoandroid\System.Net.Http.Primitives.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Runtime.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Xml.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\Xamarin.Bindings.UniversalImageLoader.1.0.4\lib\MonoAndroid\UniversalImageLoader.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable.23.3.0\lib\MonoAndroid403\Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Design.23.3.0\lib\MonoAndroid43\Xamarin.Android.Support.Design.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Percent.23.3.0\lib\MonoAndroid403\Xamarin.Android.Support.Percent.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.v13.23.3.0\lib\MonoAndroid403\Xamarin.Android.Support.v13.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4.23.3.0\lib\MonoAndroid403\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat.23.3.0\lib\MonoAndroid403\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView.23.3.0\lib\MonoAndroid403\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter.23.3.0\lib\MonoAndroid403\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView.23.3.0\lib\MonoAndroid403\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable.23.3.0\lib\MonoAndroid403\Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Analytics.29.0.0\lib\MonoAndroid41\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Analytics.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base.29.0.0\lib\MonoAndroid41\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement.29.0.0\lib\MonoAndroid41\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Gcm.29.0.0\lib\MonoAndroid41\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Gcm.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Location.29.0.0\lib\MonoAndroid41\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Location.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps.29.0.0\lib\MonoAndroid41\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Measurement.29.0.0\lib\MonoAndroid41\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Measurement.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\Xamarin.Insights.1.12.3\lib\MonoAndroid10\Xamarin.Insights.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\ZXing.Net.Mobile.2.0.4.46\lib\MonoAndroid403\ZXing.Net.Mobile.Core.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\ZXing.Net.Mobile.2.0.4.46\lib\MonoAndroid403\zxing.portable.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\ZXing.Net.Mobile.2.0.4.46\lib\MonoAndroid403\ZXingNetMobile.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Collections.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Reflection.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Threading.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Threading.Tasks.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Linq.Expressions.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\bin\Release\SQLiteNetExtensions.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.IO.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Globalization.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Linq.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Reflection.Extensions.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Net.Primitives.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Text.Encoding.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Net.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Xml.XDocument.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Dynamic.Runtime.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.ObjectModel.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll
2>      C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll
2>      C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll
2>      C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll
2>      C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Dynamic\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Dynamic.dll
2>      C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll
2>      C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll
2>      C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Numerics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Numerics.dll
2>      C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Security\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Security.dll
2>      C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.SqlXml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.SqlXml.dll
2>  GetAdditionalResourcesFromAssemblies Task
2>    AndroidSdkDirectory: C:\Android\android-sdk\
2>    AndroidNdkDirectory: C:\Android\android-ndk-r10e\
2>    Assemblies: 
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Java.Interop.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\bin\Release\MyProject.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Async.1.0.168\lib\portable-net45+win8+wpa81\Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Async.1.0.168\lib\portable-net45+win8+wpa81\Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v6.0\Mono.Android.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v6.0\Mono.Android.Export.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\mscorlib.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.8.0.3\lib\portable-net45+wp80+win8+wpa81+dnxcore50\Newtonsoft.Json.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\refit.2.4.1\lib\MonoAndroid\Refit.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\SQLite.Net.Core-PCL.3.1.1\lib\portable-win8+net45+wp8+wpa81+MonoAndroid1+MonoTouch1\SQLite.Net.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\SQLite.Net-PCL.3.1.1\lib\MonoAndroid\SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\Square.OkHttp.2.7.5.0\lib\MonoAndroid\Square.OkHttp.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\Square.OkIO.1.6.0.0\lib\MonoAndroid\Square.OkIO.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Core.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Net.Http.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\Microsoft.Net.Http.2.2.29\lib\monoandroid\System.Net.Http.Extensions.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\Microsoft.Net.Http.2.2.29\lib\monoandroid\System.Net.Http.Primitives.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Runtime.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Xml.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\Xamarin.Bindings.UniversalImageLoader.1.0.4\lib\MonoAndroid\UniversalImageLoader.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable.23.3.0\lib\MonoAndroid403\Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Design.23.3.0\lib\MonoAndroid43\Xamarin.Android.Support.Design.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Percent.23.3.0\lib\MonoAndroid403\Xamarin.Android.Support.Percent.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.v13.23.3.0\lib\MonoAndroid403\Xamarin.Android.Support.v13.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4.23.3.0\lib\MonoAndroid403\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat.23.3.0\lib\MonoAndroid403\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView.23.3.0\lib\MonoAndroid403\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter.23.3.0\lib\MonoAndroid403\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView.23.3.0\lib\MonoAndroid403\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable.23.3.0\lib\MonoAndroid403\Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Analytics.29.0.0\lib\MonoAndroid41\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Analytics.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base.29.0.0\lib\MonoAndroid41\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement.29.0.0\lib\MonoAndroid41\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Gcm.29.0.0\lib\MonoAndroid41\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Gcm.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Location.29.0.0\lib\MonoAndroid41\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Location.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps.29.0.0\lib\MonoAndroid41\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Measurement.29.0.0\lib\MonoAndroid41\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Measurement.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\Xamarin.Insights.1.12.3\lib\MonoAndroid10\Xamarin.Insights.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\ZXing.Net.Mobile.2.0.4.46\lib\MonoAndroid403\ZXing.Net.Mobile.Core.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\ZXing.Net.Mobile.2.0.4.46\lib\MonoAndroid403\zxing.portable.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\packages\ZXing.Net.Mobile.2.0.4.46\lib\MonoAndroid403\ZXingNetMobile.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Collections.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Reflection.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Threading.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Threading.Tasks.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Linq.Expressions.dll
2>      C:\MyProject\bin\Release\SQLiteNetExtensions.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.IO.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Globalization.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Linq.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Reflection.Extensions.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Net.Primitives.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Text.Encoding.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Net.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Xml.XDocument.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Dynamic.Runtime.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.ObjectModel.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll
2>      C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll
2>      C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll
2>      C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll
2>      C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Dynamic\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Dynamic.dll
2>      C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll
2>      C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll
2>      C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Numerics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Numerics.dll
2>      C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Security\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Security.dll
2>      C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.SqlXml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.SqlXml.dll
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(387,2): error : The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
2>    AdditionalAndroidResourcePaths: 
2>    AdditionalJavaLibraryReferences: 
2>    AdditionalNativeLibraryReferences: 
2>Done executing task "GetAdditionalResourcesFromAssemblies" -- FAILED.
2>Done building target "_BuildAdditionalResourcesCache" in project "MyProject.Droid.csproj" -- FAILED.
```

Comment: Can you show your stack trace..

Comment: Sorry, I just editted my post

Answer (score 4):

Edit your Android project file and add the IntermediateOutputPath property to redirect output for that project to a shorter path (can be absolute or relative).

```
<IntermediateOutputPath>..\..\shorter-path</IntermediateOutputPath>
```

Source: http://shaneneuville.com/xamarin/android/msbuild/2017/05/06/file-name-too-long.html

Answer (score 2):

We've got the same issue. I can't offer a solution, only a workaround.

It started happening when we upgraded Xamarin to the latest version, so I guess as a last resort, you could downgrade back to the previous version.

Rich

UPDATE: We were running the CC.NET service (which calls MSBuild) under the LocalSystem account. This meant that the AppData path was much longer than that of a regular user, so I created a regular user account and ran the CC.NET service as this user. This fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same issue, can't solve it yet, but it looks like that the resourcepaths.cache file is not being created, because the path to the systemprofile appdata is too long.

```
C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Xamarin\
C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable\23.4.0.0\embedded
C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable\23.4.0.0\embedded\classes.jar
```

Still strange as the directory is 130 characters long and the file 142.

Only way to solve it for now, is running builds as local administrator.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by running Visual Studio as an Administrator, and by unchecking:

- Use Shared Runtime
- Enable developer instrumentation (debugging and profiling)

  in Droid project properties, on **Android Options** tab.